# Query VMWare by ManagedObjectReference?

Tags: c#, vmware

I'm using the PowerCLI VMWare.Vim dll, but I'm using it in C#.

Below is the code.

```
VimClient c = new VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl();
ServiceContent sc = c.Connect("");
UserSession us = c.Login("", "");

NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
filter.Add("MoRef", "VirtualMachine-vm-12294");

 IList<VMware.Vim.EntityViewBase> vms2 = c.FindEntityViews(typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), null, filter, null);
```

The c.FindEntityViews throws an InvalidProperty exception.

I've looked all over the place, and I STILL can't figure out how to query the vmware stuff by the MoRef directly.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a long time coming, but here's the answer to the question.

```
VimClient c = new VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl();
ServiceContent sc = c.Connect("");
UserSession us = c.Login("", "");

NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
filter.Add("Id", "vm-12294");

 IList<VMware.Vim.EntityViewBase> vms2 = 
c.FindEntityViews(typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), null, filter, null);
```

Note that we filter by "Id" and remove the "VirtualMachine-" from MoRef of "VirtualMachine-vm-12294".  Technically speaking the ID is "vm-12294" and the MoRef string of "VirtualMachine-vm-12294" is a type indicator and not part of the actual id.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in 2021.  The property Id isn't recognized.

Answer (score 2):

For whom might need it...

You can use this `VimClient.GetView` Method, see the OverloadDefinitions:

```
VimClient.GetView(VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference moRef, string[] properties)
```

For example:

```
_vimClient.GetView(new ManagedObjectReference("VirtualMachine-vm-12294"),null);
```